# play back error in mtm 2012,microsoft visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, playback, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager, manual-testing

We have Angular Single Page Application for which we are creating test cases.
We have a test case written for Login page (loading of page, username, password entry, and login btn click action). While recording the actions the flow is as expected and once the validations are met the page is transferred to our applications home page.
However when we playback the recording the all actions take place as excepted and we get replies for login api calls. But the browser doesn't get transferred to applications home page. Its stuck on the login page forever.

And this case only happens in Single Page Application. When we try the same in Normal web application it works perfectly fine. The page gets transferred as expected in the playback.

And i have tired in coded ui test for existing recording,the browser doesn't get transferred to the application home page.

Could you let us know what should we investigate and how to proceed further.